# Trying to co-relate MVC with respect to AngularJS architecture

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, model-view-controller, mvvm

AngularJS earlier defined MVC as MVVM and now it is MVW:
Confusion: How to co-relate MVC with MVVM or MVW. 
All of us relate Model with data. So Model part is fine
View is the presentation. So View is also fine
ViewModel: Also called Scope ; This confuses me . "Scope is a glue". Is is somewhat related to controller ? what about the controllers that we define explicitly using module.controller.

Whatever : is whatever a controller ?

In backbone things are specific . Like model is data, view is the UI and controller has the manipulating functions that act on model.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is not a controller, but yes u r right that scope is a glue between the view and the controller. Angular binds everything with scope and look for changes in that which happens in $digest function internally and updates the model.

So, suppose in your view you have {{id}} then in this should be defined assosiated to a scope like $scope.id. Refer to **doc** or **jenkov.com** which clearly explains all this.